# Change character used to create git commit link to work item

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps automatically links work items to commits if you include a # reference to the work item in your commit message.

For example, if I had the following commit message

`Did work to complete work item #721`

It would automatically link to work item with Id 721.

I am wondering if it is possible to change the # character that Azure DevOps uses to automatically link to something else?

Say for example I wanted to use $ as my auto-link character.

`Did work to complete work item $721`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example I wanted to use $ as my auto-link character.
>
> Did work to complete work item $721
>
> Is that possible?

Sorry to say, No, until now, `#ID` is the only symbol which can be interpreted as **link** by Azure Devops.

The process of interpret is finding a work item which id=172 exists in this project, so create a link to this work item.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It would be nice to be able to specify this because a client of mine want's to differentiate their work item links from work item links from upstream fork that also uses # reference links.  He is currently getting commits from the upstream linking to unrelated work items because the Id's happen to match.

Comment: Our solution to this problem at the moment is to turn off auto linking and to create a bit of code to use the API to create the links for us

Comment: Like this, I recommend you raise your suggestion and your demand in our 
[Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) . The Azure Product team will consider your feature suggestion. It may help build more feature in Azure Devops.